What is happening with login today?
Stack Overflow: logged in, as usual, with GitHub credentials.
Meta and other communities: I am still logged out, and the login dialogue has the GitHub credential option missing.
At the same time, my inbox shows messages and reputation changes from the other communities.
Is this a glitch? Is it intentional? How should I proceed?

Interesting question. Would the result of security hardening in browsers be considered a glitch? In the most technical sense yes, but it'd be one you have to live with.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78272502/1968
